# Does Pinging Client PCs every five seconds cause problems?

Tags: windows, networking

I have a gaming zone where I have 20 client PCs and a server. If I run a script(PHP/VB.NET) from my server that pings client PCs every five seconds to see if they are turned on/off, will it cause any problem to the users who are playing games? Or does it have any negative effect to the performance of the computers I have while they are running?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: I think pinging a few packets won't affect performance that much given today's bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ping is fairly low cost, it only sends a few bytes and measures how fast it receives an answer from the target computer. It shouldn't cause any noticeable loss in performance on the target computers if you're just pinging once every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It will not create any mess, if the PCs are fitted with modern days processor and, moreover, modern days LAN ports on Switches are having speed gigabits ports.

Let the ping be at `bytes=32` (default), don't manually change it to higher bytes.

Answer (score 0):

you maybe need a heartbeat task ... just Like a thread & socket with HeartBeat